# C call to NetShareEnum fails with 5 'Access Denied' on Win 10 while same user can browse the SMB shares

Tags: c, windows, network-programming, smb

We're running Win10 LTS-B.
Using SMB shares and no domain.

The user is able to access the remote share using file explorer.
But the signed executable which runs as the same user
fails with code 5 'access denied' when calling the function "netShareEnum".

The code is a direct copy from the msdn example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netshareenum

When starting the executable,
The remote systen with the SMB share shows in the Eventlog "security" a successful login, and approx 10 seconds later a logoff entry.(seems triggered by my call)
So something else is wrong.

I dont know where to look next..
I also enabled dcom/ole access- and failure-logging on the remote system in the hope of finding something, but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it ! :) It was because someone pressed [cancel] on the next popup
[image]